# Deploy Blazor Client(WebAssembly) on Docker that time facing issue

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0

When I deploy/run the project on Docker that time I am facing an issue.
Facing issues like,

> Cannot use file stream for
> [/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/projectname.deps.json]: No such file or
> directory A fatal error was encountered. The library
> 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found
> in '/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/'. Failed to run as a self-contained app.
>
> - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/projectname.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
> - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/projectname.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify
>   the appropriate framework.

and face issue when I run a project with docker on Visual Studio 2022.

[image: face issue when I run project with docker on Visual Studio 2022.]

If anyone has an idea about his please share it with me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add Docker File with Nginx Reverse Proxy Server**

For Blazor Web Assembly we need to add "nginx.conf" in Project root folder

```
events { }
http {
   include mime.types;
   types {
      application/wasm wasm;
   }
   server {
      listen 80;
     # Here, we set the location for Nginx to serve the files looking for index.html
     location / {
        root .;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
     }
  }
}
```

Now in Dockerfile mention it like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["projectpath/projectname.csproj", "projectpath"]
RUN dotnet restore "projectpath/projectname.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/projectpath"
RUN dotnet build "projectname.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "projectname.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectname.dll"]

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
#Copy from Environment(build/publish)
COPY --from=publish app/publish/wwwroot .
```

Now build and run the project in docker.